# Извлечение из .txt файла чисел и запись этих чисел в переменные

Tags: python, python-3.x, файловый-ввод-вывод

### Напишите программу по которой из текстового файла с именем abc.txt будут прочитаны три числа: a,b,c и записаны в переменные.

```
Мой код:

with open('abc.txt', 'rt') as file:    #открываю файл abc.txt

    q=file.read()    #считываю содержимое файла в переменную q

    q=q.replace(' ', '').split()    #обновляю q (удаляю лишние пробелы)
```

Но что делать дальше? На данный момент q=['132']. Как мне извлечь из текстового списка отдельно единицу, отдельно 3 и отдельно 2?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А зачем Вам удалять пробелы перед сплитом? Не проще сплитнуть по нему изначально и получить 3 числа? Можете еще обрезать внешние пробелы методом `.strip()`

Comment: извините за глупый вопрос, но не подскажите что именно делает метод .split()?

Comment: Разбивает строку по разделителю на список элементов.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
a, b, c = (int(s) for s in q.split())
```

Comment: что за переменная s?

Comment: Опечатка. Исправил.

Comment: А можно так: `a, b, c = map(int, q.split())`

Comment: @gil9red можно, но Гвидо ругается :)

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev [Гвидо](https://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=98196) ругается, но аргументированно лишь против связки map+lamda. Просто map, показывает что может быть заменен, но без аргументов преимущества.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev, а мы ему не будем об этом рассказывать ;)

Answer (score 2):

Решение в функциональном стиле:

```
a, b, c = map(int, q.split())
```

Пример:

```
q = "12 1 4"
a, b, c = map(int, q.split())
print(a, b, c)  # 12 1 4
```